# Rails: has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models in my app:

Position:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :report_to_position, class_name: 'Position', foreign_key: 'report_to_position_id'
  has_many   :employees

end
```

Employee:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :position

  def boss
    self.position.report_to_position.employee
  end

end
```

As you can see in `boss` getter I need to get one `employee` in this relation. The problem is `Position` class has many `employees`. How can I get just one object (boss for many employees) with this model logic?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know they're the boss?

Comment: @Baloo I shouldn't add any fields for employees. All that I have is that `self.position.report_to_position.employee` relation

Comment: I'm not asking you to, but there has to be something that shows you they're the boss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get *the* boss with this association setup, but you can get *a* boss. That is: you can get a superior. The `Position` class `has_many :employees`, which gives you two problems:

1. There's nothing in the `Employee` class to say "this is my direct superior".
2. There's nothing in the whole system to say "only one person can hold a position".
3. There's nothing in the `Position` class to say "this person is the boss".

That might be OK; if it's OK to get an (essentially random) superior for a given `Employee`, your boss method could read as follows:

```
def boss
  self.position.report_to_position.employees.first
end
```

---

Overall, though, I'd rethink your schema. It's OK to keep your org chart and employee data separate, but you should consider moving the boss/subordinates associations to the `Employee` itself via a [self join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins):

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee", foreign_key: "boss_id" 
  belongs_to :boss, class_name: "Employee"
  belongs_to :position
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Structure**

To help define `Alex P`'s answer, you'll need to look at how you're *defining* the `boss` record in your associations, and tables.

The problem I can see is that because all your `employee` associative data is all the same, you have no way to determine who is the "boss" or not, hence your issue

There are two ways to ensure you have the `boss` association defined -

> 1. In the `ActiveRecord` associations
> 2. In the database / `Model`

--

**Association**

Probably the most reliable way to do this is to use an `association`, as described by `Alex P`:

```
#app/models/employee.rb
Class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :boss, class_name: "Employee"
   has_one :boss, class_name: "Employee", foreign_key: "boss_id"
end
```

--

**Model**

The way I would do it is to use the [`Ancestry` gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) -

```
#app/models/employee.rb
Class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_ancestry
end
```

This has to be coupled with a datatable column called `ancestry` (`string`):

[image]

This will allow you to give each `employee` a *Parent* (who could be a Boss or a Manager etc). The beauty of this setup will be that you can create a real "tree" structure - employees will be able to have multiple managers / bosses as required